# TOM ADOMD.NET - What is "Retains dimensionality"?

Tags: c#, ssas-tabular, azure-analysis-services, adomd.net, tom

I try to see the documentation of Microsoft but I can't understand when they said "Retains dimensionality". What does it mean?

They describe it in the table of this link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/adomd/multidimensional-models-adomd-net-client/retrieving-data-from-an-analytical-data-source?view=asallproducts-allversions

I would like if you explain me the differences and an example where affect

Answer (score 1):

Basically it means that the data structure containing the data isn't a simple table with rows and columns, but a "multi-dimensional" data structure where data is stored in the intersection of multiple axes. One axis might be Year/Month/Day, and another Country/State/Zip, and another CustomerId.  Then at each intersection you have measures like TotalSales, ItemCount, etc.

This is for MDX queries.

See [CellSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.analysisservices.adomdclient.cellset?view=analysisservices-dotnet).